# Sending messages to other shards on Discord.js v12+

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a system inside my Discord bot where it relies on channel ids to post to from a database of Channel IDs (eg: 1234567891234).

Now my main issue is being able to send to that channel via the ID as I am using [Discord.JS](https://discordjs.guide) v12+ with the ShardingManager.

I have this basic code but unsure as to how I would relay that message from one channel to another channel thats on a different shard to the OP Shard.

```js
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
(async () => {
    const channel = await this.channels.cache.get('683353482748756047');
    if (channel) {
        channel.send("hi");
    }
})();
`);
```

I'm hoping to be able to pull this off, but I have been advised to use [Discord's](https://discord.com) REST API system, but I'm not that advanced to understand each segment of their API Network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I answered my own question without realising it;

```js
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
(async () => {
    const channel = await this.channels.cache.get('${where.id}');
    if (channel) {
        channel.send("Hi");
    }
})();
`);
```

Now I just need to add the embed function it lol.

I hope this helps anyone using the ShardingManager from Discord.js.